# Bower+Gulp: Minify all CSS into one file

Tags: gulp, bower

I'm new to Bower and I would like to use Gulp to handle CSS & JS loading and minification.

I've already solved (I hope) JS minification. But with CSS I found several problems, and not all of them I was able to solve:

1. CSS files which are not found by `gulp-main-bower-files` plugin. For example CSS styles for jQuery UI. Solved by `gulp-add-src` plugin.
2. Minimizing styles including `@import` command. Solved by `gulp-cssimport` plugin.
3. **Image paths in CSS file.** Don't know how to solve it when I minimize all CSS into one style. When I minimize CSS with relative paths (for example `background: url('../images/bg1.jpg')`), minimized file has different location than original one, so path is not working.
4. **Fonts paths in CSS file.** Also don't know how to solve it. It's the same problem as above. For example with the result of Gulp task below, **I'm not able to use Bootstrap icons**.

My Gulp task for minify CSS looks like this:

```js
var mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var cssimport = require('gulp-cssimport');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

var src = 'www/bower_components/';
var dest = 'www/bower_components/_compiled/';

gulp.task('css', function() {
 gulp.src('./bower.json')
  .pipe(mainBowerFiles())
  .pipe(filter('**/*.css'))
  .pipe(addsrc(src+'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css')).pipe(cssimport())
  .pipe(addsrc(src+'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')).pipe(cssimport())
  .pipe(addsrc(src+'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css')).pipe(cssimport())
  .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))
  .pipe(cleanCSS())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

**gulp-clean-css** is absolutelly briliant plugin which can handle all of this (both `@import` and *relative paths*). It is just necesary to **use first clean-css and THEN concat styles into one file** (I did it opposite).

If anyone interested, I attach my entire `gulpfile.js`:

```js
// Include Gulp & plugins
var gulp           = require('gulp');
var mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var addSrc         = require('gulp-add-src');  // .pipe(addSrc('www/bower_files/foo.js'))
var order          = require('gulp-order');
var concat         = require('gulp-concat');
var filter         = require('gulp-filter');
var uglify         = require('gulp-uglify');
var cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css');

// Settings
var dest = 'www/bower_components/';

var bowerOptions = {overrides: {
 'bootstrap': {main: [
  'dist/js/bootstrap.js',
  'dist/css/bootstrap.css',
  'dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
 ]},
 'jquery-ui': {main: [
  'jquery-ui.js',
  'themes/base/all.css',
 ]},
}};


// Tasks
gulp.task('css', function() {
 gulp.src('./bower.json')
  .pipe(mainBowerFiles(bowerOptions))
  .pipe(filter('**/*.css'))
  .pipe(cleanCSS({rebaseTo: dest}))
  .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
 gulp.src('./bower.json')
  .pipe(mainBowerFiles(bowerOptions))
  .pipe(filter('**/*.js'))
  .pipe(order([
   '**/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
   '**/nette.ajax.js',
   '**/*',
  ]))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css']);
```